# Debugging jquery for IE 8, why it wouldn't work?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm making a very simple gallery using jquery, it works in all browsers but fails in IE8 and 7.

Any ideas why and how would I debug it?

```
//Gallery system, single and compare pages
function makeGallery (whichThumb,whichMainImage,whichImageWrap) {
    $(whichThumb).live("click", function() {
        $(whichMainImage).hide();
        $(whichImageWrap).css('background-image', "url('images/no-image.png')");
        var i = $('<img />').attr('src',this.href).load(function() {
            $(whichMainImage).attr('src', i.attr('src'));
            $(whichImageWrap).css('background-image', 'none');
            $(whichMainImage).fadeIn();
        });
        return false; 
    });
} // End makeGallery
```

What happens is that image changes to `no-image.png` and nothing happens after that...
I'm setting up jsfiddle for demonstration...

Comment: You know live is deprecated and not even present in recent versions of jQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reverse setting the onload callback and src :

```
  var i = $('<img />');
  i.load(function() {
        $(whichMainImage).attr('src', i.attr('src'));
        $(whichImageWrap).css('background-image', 'none');
        $(whichMainImage).fadeIn();
  });
  i.attr('src',this.href);
```

On old ie versions you wouldn't have the callback called if the browser is fast enough to fetch the image (from cache for example) and it's generally the best practice to use this order.

As live was deprecated a long time and is now removed from last versions, you should use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: thanks :) no I didn't know live was depreciated. I rarely do jquery.